# Using Mule Studio to create a pattern based project

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I would like to use Mule Studio to create a simple mule configuration based on the Web Service Proxy pattern:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Proxy+Pattern

I could not find graphical components in Mule Studio for this. Is it correct to assume that mule configuration patterns are not directly supported by the Mule Studio graphical editor, - and would i need to make a mule-config.xml instead of a mflow-file?

If so, what would be the best practice for working in Mule Studio with services that require pure mule-config.cml instead of mflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mule Studio does not support (yet) all the possible xml configuration supported by Mule.

When it comes to Patterns you should switch to the xml view and add your configuration there.